# How to use js to control actionscript on another page?

Tags: javascript, flash, actionscript

I know it's pretty easy to connect flash and js on one page by using external interface call.

But how would you connect a flash with the js on another page?

For example, if I had a flash game opened on one computer, but the user can only interact with the game with js on another computer. \

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you would be able to get these two things to communicate separately without some kind of medium or using **XML Sockets**. If it doesn't need to be real-time, then consider sending/receiving data to/from a MySQL server. If it does - I know you'll need to look at XML sockets - I'm just not 100% on how they are used as I've never had the resources to experiment.

Answer (score 0):

I don't thinks this is possible. Only using some server-side programming ou multiplayer server, etc.

Using LocalConnection your SWFs can comunicate to each other, but they need to stay in the same page, same user.